# Normalize sentence with words

Tags: nlp-compromise

I tried to normalize this sentence 'Select two Holds' with that code:

```
        const config = {numbers: true, case: true, plurals:true, whitespace: true}
    const text = this.state.nlp(this.state.sentense);
    console.log(text.debug());
    text.normalize(config)

    this.setState({result: text.out('text')});
```

The result is: "select 2 hold".

If I changed the sentence for: 'Select two holds' the result is: "select 2 holds". I output the debug and I seen that when I typed Holds it see 'Holds' as a noun but when I typed 'holds' it see it as a verb.

Is there a way to override the rule or something like that so that it will remove the 's' of holds or any words on every way is written?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the library nlp-compromise had incorrectly interpreted the verb hold and the noun hold. So I force the library with a tagging to see the verb as a noun so it will  normalize the word correctly.

Config:
        result.match('#Infinitive #Value [#PresentTense]').tag('Noun');